Can't completely uninstall wine following a power failure
I tried to install Wine via the terminal, but there was a power failure during the installation of Wine. Now I can't uninstall Wine completely or proceed from where I stopped.

You may try sudo dpkg --configure -a, which may help if the installation was stopped during the configuration stage. If that doesn't work, please edit your question (please don't post the output of the command as a comment) adding the output of sudo apt install --reinstall wine so that we can look at the specific error message.

Check Wine and Wine-related packages for incompletely installed packages.

Run dpkg -l | grep wine to list all Wine-related packages.

The status of a package is shown by a two-letter code that precedes the package's name in the results of dpkg -l | grep wine Look for any packages with a status of hh (half-installed) or cc (configuration files only).


Remove incomplete packages.

Run history 20 to list the last 20 commands that you ran, and search for the package name of the Wine package that you tried to install and the command that you ran to install it.
For incomplete packages, run the command sudo apt --reinstall install wine. This will reinstall the wine package and its dependencies and complete the installation process. For wine substitute the package name of the Wine package that you tried to install before.


I'm not going to explain how to use sudo apt purge wine and sudo apt autoremove yet because hopefully you won't need them.
